# How to use storeHtmlSource in python code (Selenium RC)

Tags: python, html, selenium

I found storeHtmlSource method description in [Selenium reference](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/core/reference.html), but can't figure out how to use it in python code I generated by exporting recording of my actions from the Selenium IDE.

I need to pass the html source code of the current page into a function for processing. How to do that? Can anyone show example of code for calling this method? Could it at all to be called from python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't speak for Python, but check out the getHtmlSource method for the Java API of the [Selenium interface](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-remote-control/1.0-beta-2/doc/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/Selenium.html). It explains what it does pretty clearly.